# Mac: disable the "boop" sound played when search results are not found

Tags: macos, audio, user-interface

When you search in a page in many Mac applications (Firefox, Chrome, TextMate), a sound is played when results are not found. It's the "boop" sound that usually indicates that you are unable to perform an action (eg click a window, etc.)

I use the passive voice because I don't how this sound is played, or if each app implements this differently. In any case, it quickly gets annoying -- is there a way to disable it just for search?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is the default "alert" sound used as the audible bell.

#### Disable alert sounds altogether

You can generally disable it by lowering the volume — Note that unchecking "Play user interface sound effects" is **not** the same but it only disables sound effects from Finder, etc. The alert will still go.

Also, as far as I'm concerned, you can't disable it just for some apps.

[image]

#### Alerts in Firefox

Firefox seems to have special settings that you can access in `about:config`. You can disable those, although I personally didn't hear any sounds when searching in Firefox (4.0.1), but this could be OS specific?

[image]

Comment: I was getting the "Glass" sound after updating FF. Setting `accessibility.typeaheadfind.enablesound` to `false` fixed it, thanks!