# How do you mute the ding sound in Google Chrome when find on page returns no results?

Tags: windows-7, windows, google-chrome, audio

In Google Chrome, on Windows 7, if you hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> and you type in random letters, you will hear a ding sound. I want to mute that sound.

How would I go about doing that?

Comment: Not sure what OS you're on but http://superuser.com/questions/278142/mac-disable-the-boop-sound-played-when-search-results-are-not-found

Comment: The answer for a windows-based system is going to be almost exactly the same I'm afraid.  That "ding" is the windows 'Asterisk' sound.  You can get at it through the control panel -> Hardware and Sound -> Change system sounds.  You'll have to set it to 'none' to get rid of the ding.

Comment: That "ding" sound you refer to is beyond annoying. It's overkill and obtrusive. Negative results should be implied graphically. E.g. Red background colour or a red cross.

Comment: This ding sound is the worse thing in the world. You can get it like 3-4 times in one second.

Answer (score 77, accepted):

Not sure why this was so hard to find on the internet - no one mentions it in relation to this specific problem as far as I could tell, and I looked for a while. I had the same problem too, but in Windows 10. Absolutely hate that sound.

Click:

1. Start
2. Control Panel
3. Hardware and Sound
4. Sound
5. Open Sounds Tab

(alternatively, just search for "change system sounds" in the lower left search bar in your Windows task bar)

look for the "Default Beep" event in the list there, and change the Sounds value to none. Chrome should not make that sound anymore. Makes sense that Chrome would use the default beep on Windows too.

Comment: Thank you, It saved my Laptop from crashing on Floor.

Answer (score 2):

The answer for a windows-based system is going to be almost exactly the same as the link in Dave's comment I'm afraid.

That "ding" is the windows 'Asterisk' sound. You can get at it through the control panel -> Hardware and Sound -> Change system sounds. You'll have to set it to 'none' to get rid of the ding.

Answer (score 1):

Panhandel is almost correct - you need to go to control panel -> Hardware and Sound -> Change system sounds but it isn't the asterisk. If you scroll all the way to the bottom of the sound list you will see "Start Navigation." Set this sound to "none" and click apply. Then click OK. The sound should be gone now :)

Comment: I use windows 7 and the answer provided by @unami worked for me. However, those of panhandel and Callie did not work. Thus the irritating sound is indeed "Default Beep"

Answer (score -1):

For me it was an add-on called Download Plus. Even though I had Windows sounds set to None it still gave this annoying notification. You can turn it off in Download Plus settings. It's the first option listed, almost like even they knew how bad it sounded. Hope this helped someone.

And by the way, it took 5 minutes of clicking to get through the captcha. Almost gave up. You should try a less troublesome one.

Comment: (1) Where can one get ‘‘Download Plus’’?  Can you give any other information about it, like what it does and how to use it?  (Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your question to make it clearer and more complete.)  (2) If you hang around for a while and provide useful, spam-free content, the CAPTCHA requests will drop to nearly zero.